# What is the range of motion of a raptor wrist?

Tags: dinosaurs

I have been trying to find out how much could raptor like dinosaurs move their wrists.
I know that this will vary between species, so let's say for example a deinonychus.
I am aware that the usual movie depiction of pronated wrists is wrong.
But I want to know the range of motion of the real animal.

Sometimes they are drawn with fingers pointing back to the tail, sometimes down to the ground and sometimes forward.
So were they able to rotate the wrist the full 180 degrees or where the truth is?

A couple of examples what I mean.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deinonychus#/media/File:Deinonychus_Restoration.png
Fingers down:
[image]

Fingers forward (Same wiki page):
[image]

Thanks.